# How can physical predictions be useful given that they're based on fallible assumptions?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

Can we assume things we don't know?

For example, a bullet of mass $m$ and velocity $v$ is fired from height $h$. At what distance does it land?  We can say$$
\text{distance}~=~v \sqrt{\frac{h}{g}}
\,,$$though are we able to say that we don't know where it lands because maybe the bullet explode or maybe blocked by a tree, etc.?

Why are these assumptions not taken into consideration?  Is a philosophical concept behind this?

Comment: It’s just the model assumptions - the derived formula for the distance assumes that the only force acting on the bullet over the whole trajectory (Ie until it hits the ground) is gravity.

Comment: Are you serious? All questions have a context.

Comment: thanks for the answer. What i concluded is that if we take consideration all of this probable scenarios in the end of day we get nothing. so we take the most common scenario . But if we want to make it more complicated we must refer the assumption right ? imagine we having an exam test and we have to solve a problem like above..we cant start saying what if what if what if etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not expressing yourself as well as you would like.
Every physical model is mathematical in nature and has several assumptions. If you want to know were the bullet will land you use that formula, assuming the bullet won't explode or go into a tree and assuming a thousand other "unsaid" assumptions that come from common sense. Nevertheless if you really which to know were the bullet will land without all those assumptions you would have a different model (stochastic) with probabilities for several other thing that might happen to the bullet. But you will never have a model with no assumptions because it impossible to account all the millions of different possibilities so, in general, you just take into consideration the things that are relatively probable to happen to the bullet.

Example: In a battlefield you have your rifle pointing in certain direction and you wish to know we're is the bullet going to land. If you assume nothing happens to the bullet in it's path (which is a fair assumption because the probability of such a thing is really low) you can say it will land at point A. But you can take into consideration that it might get hit by another bullet, or it might hit someone and then you get different results but there are still millions of possibilities you did not consider (like a piece of scrap from a plane flying by being dropped and stopping the bullet in its path) because the're probability is so low it is not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You ask a very good question.  Few people bother to ask it.  It is, of course, a very difficult question to answer.  I will do my best, and hopefully that helps.

There are two steps to the process.  The first is that one must identify a model they wish to use.  In your bullet case, it is a model of a simple object flying with no air resistance fired horizontally.

Assumptions:

- Bullet fired perfectly horizontally -- velocity is horizontal as it leaves the barrel
- Negligible air resistance
- Rotating effects of the earth are negligible.
- Bullet travel is short enough that the curvature of the earth is negligible.
- No trees or walls in the way which would cause collisions
- Negligable electromagnetic effects
- [There is no Dana, only Zuul](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lg7MAacSPNM). (Okay, maybe this last one isn't *actually* an assumption in the model.  You get the idea).

Now at the moment this is just a model.  It has not been connected to reality in any way.

The next step is to decide the model has predictive power.  This is the heart of the question.   To that end, I recommend a quote:

> All models are wrong.  Some are useful.

Your model doesn't account for air resistance.  Thus we *know* for a fact that it is wrong (unless you're in space).  But it can still be useful if we determine that it is "close enough."

How do you determine close enough?  Practice.  The difference between an engineer fresh out of school and an engineer with 20 years of experience is mostly that the experienced engineer tends to know when a model will be useful and when it won't be.

Philosophically there's a few tools that can be used.  The most important is [abduction](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/abduction/), which is the assumption that the most likely hypothesis is true.  That can be combined with some math ([perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory), in particular) which can show that it's *likely* that certain effects will not matter, which then feeds into the argument via abduction.  Likewise, abduction can be used to rule out the possibility that there is somehow a tree in front of the bullet despite the fact that you can't see the tree.  It's highly unlikely that there's an invisible tree in the way.

However, this assumption would be poor if you were firing blindfolded.  Never fire a firearm blindfolded.  It is not safe.... and apparently there might be a tree in your way.

Oh, and when someone asks you if you are a god, [you say yes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6LD6ITN2dk)!